# OpenLayers keyboard zoom not working in electron environment

Tags: electron, openlayers

I have a electron app that is used to do network graph analysis based on real world graphs such as electric networks. At the moment I'm trying to implement an option where I layer the graph over a map and one can see the exact position of the nodes on the map. It looks like this:

[image]

Adding the map is done by open layers. I also want to be able to pan and zoom in while the map is shown. For this the map and graph have to move together. This should be possible with keyboard commands of the arrow keys and + and - .

When I use the arrow keys to direct up ,down ,left ,right everything works apart from open layers loading the map slower than the graph moves sometimes. But when I zoom with the keyboard the map from open layers is not zooming at all. I also tried every key on the keyboard and apparently there is not a single key that zooms the map eventho I activated the keyboard in the options.

The + and - keys generally work in the electron app so this is not a problem. Furthermore, the graph also zooms. It's just the map that does not.

Is there a way to fix this? If not what would be the best option to find a different solution than using the keyboard buttons?

Comment: Are you using `keyboardEventTarget: document` in the map options?

Comment: Yes, thats what im using since the map is behind the graph.